# How to disable anti-aliasing in QMovie(or QLabel)?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to use QMovie in QLabel to show a pixel animation but anti-aliasing seems to be enabled by default. This makes the pixel painting not look like a pixel painting.

```
QMovie* movie = new QMovie(":/gif/exp.gif");
movie->setScaledSize(QSize(200,200));
label->setMovie(movie);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QMovie](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmovie.html) just play your gif inside label, It didn't change anti-aliasing, If you didn't see that gif with the high quality you should change that `gif`.

> The QMovie class is a convenience class for **playing** movies with
> QImageReader.

this means that it didn't use paint.

one thing that makes you see that gif in low quality is for change scale `movie->setScaledSize(QSize(200,200));`

If you remove this you can see what your gif is actually, with that original quality.